# Cannot resolve symbol 'expected'

Tags: java

can you help me why intelijIDEA throws me an error when in assertEquals I specify 'expected' and another argument?
The error says Cannot resolve symbol 'expected'

Here is my code:

```
package rs.ac.singidunum;
    
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
    
class KalkulatorTest {
    
    @Test
    void getA() {
        Kalkulator k1= new Kalkulator(4,6);
        double rezultat = k1.getA();
        assertEquals( expected: 4, rezultat );
    }
    
    
    @Test
    void getB() {
        Kalkulator k1= new Kalkulator(4,6);
        double rezultat = k1.getB();
        assertEquals(expected: 6, rezultat);
    }
    
    @Test
    void saberi() {
        Kalkulator k1 = new Kalkulator(3,5);
        double rezultat = k1.saberi();
        assertEquals(expected:8, rezultat);
    }
    
    @Test
    void oduzmi() {
        Kalkulator k1 = new Kalkulator(4,6);
        double rezultat = k1.oduzmi();
        assertEquals(expected:-2, rezultat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Comment: `expected: 6` let me guess: you are learning from a video made by someone using intellij? that's a label that the IDE shows, you have to write only `assertEquals(6, rezultat);`

Comment: OMG!!!!! Thank y so much! That solved my problem.  yes, I am learning from my

Comment: I am learning from a video from my college assistant

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't think that duplicate target actually explains the particular problem with this code, i.e. the use of name labels on the method parameters.